# How to use environment variables in Idea settings

Tags: intellij-idea

Let's say I would like to point to the Maven home via environmental variable, rather than enetering the actual path. When I use `"$env.M2_HOME$"` in mavenVersion.xml Idea seems to get it when loading the file:

```
<application>
  <component name="MavenVersion" mavenHome="$env.M2_HOME$" />
</application>
```

I can see the expanded value in `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven` -> Maven home directory.

...but whenever Idea decides to save its settings it does so in their expanded form:

```
<application>
  <component name="MavenVersion" mavenHome="C:/apache-maven-3.3.9" />
</application>
```

I was thinking maybe one could make use of `Appearance & Behavior -> Path Variables` but Idea does not appear to allow entering anything but actual directory/path in `Build, Execution, Deployment -> Build Tools -> Maven` -> Maven home directory.

Am I out of luck here?

Answer (score 2):

Answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44758883/224239

In a nutshell: Define a **Path Variable** (e.g. MAVEN_HOME) with value matching your `Maven home directory`. When saving your project or general settings Idea will replace the value of `Maven home directory` with its respective variable placeholder...
...mavenVersion.xml will then look like this:

```
<application>
  <component name="MavenVersion" mavenHome="$MAVEN_HOME$" />
</application>
```

When using together with **Settings Repository** make sure to add `_windows/path.macros.xml` to your `<userhome>/.IntelliJIdea<version>/config/settingsRepository/repository/.gitignore` so you don't share machine-specific Path Variables across all your machines.